# Calculating number of items in a summed series - non-repeating connections between points

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, connections

I would like to calculate the number of possible connections in a set of points, and although I can express the idea in a mathematical formula, I don't know how to "reduce" it to a working calculation.

Let's say I have points A to F that I want to interconnect. I can illustrate the task like so:

```
A  (B C D E F)
B  (C D E F)
C  (D E F)
D  (E F)
E  (F)
F  --
```

We start with A, connecting to B C D E F, then move on to B and connect to C D E F, omitting A as we already have the A-B connection from the previous step. And so on until F, where we create no new connections, given that all points are already connected to F.

Mathematically I can state this summing as:

`(N-1)+(N-2)+(N-3) ... + (N-(N-1))`

That's as far as I can get. I'm not a mathematician and don't know how to go from there to a solution.

I also suspect that what I'm doing here is a known problem in math. Does it have a name that I could look up?

Comment: You want [AP sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)? Another way to express the value you want is ${n\choose 2}$

Comment: Thank you! The Wikipedia page you linked to provides the solution. I'll wait a couple of days if anyone wants to write it up here as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll make the comment an answer. The derivation of AP sum is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).
Another way you can count pairs of elements of a set of cardinality $n$ is ${n\choose 2}$ (MathJax `${n\choose 2}$`) -- is number of ways to choose $2$ items out of $n$ distinct items irrecpective of order.
The formula of number of [$k-$combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is $${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
and for $k=2$ this gives the same formula $${n\choose k}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't seem right or applicable in my case. The formula I used from that page was to take the first and last numbers in the series - in my example 5 and 1, add them together, multiply by number of elements (5 in my case), and divide by 2. So `n*(a+z)/2`, where a is first number and z is last. The result is 15, the correct count. Your formula would be `5*(5-1)/2`, resulting in 10.

Comment: Hmmm don't you sum up $n-1$ terms from $n-1$ to $1$? Giving $\frac{(n-1)+1}{2}\cdot (n-1)$? `(N-1)+(N-2)+(N-3) ... + (N-(N-1))`(sic)

Comment: That works! But is that the same formula as in your answer? At any rate, we have a small misunderstanding now in terms of what `n` is. You're using my original formula, where `n` is 6, the total number of points. But to use the formula from the Wiki page, I set `n` to 5, the number of non-null items. One way or another, it appears that more than one formula may be used to arrive at the correct solution. I would accept your answer if it was clear how it leads to the correct solution.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I get it. The answer is correct - accepted. Thanks again.